# Creating session in hibernate taking more than 40 sec

Tags: java, database, hibernate, session

I am using hibernate framework for accessing database. It is taking more 40 sec to create session. What would be the reason for taking that much time?

```
SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

This is the line chich takes too much time to fininsh.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://54.64.5.134:3306/cpos</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
    <property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/ehcache.xml</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>

    <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">3000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>



    <mapping class="com.chaipoint.dppojos.CpOrderAddress" />
    <mapping class="com.chaipoint.dppojos.CpOrders" />
    <mapping class="com.chaipoint.dppojos.LocationMaster" />
    <mapping class="com.chaipoint.dppojos.CpOrderProduct" />
    <mapping class="com.chaipoint.dppojos.StoreMaster" />



</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And here is my hibernate.cgf.xml file

Comment: There are many possible reasons, too many to answer without more informations.

Comment: @maman:share your hibernate config files

Comment: SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

Comment: @XvolksThis is the line I am taking too much time.

Comment: I have updated my post . Have a look. @Lathy

Comment: What happens, if you remove this `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>`?

Comment: Did you try using a profiler?

Comment: @v.ladynev It is working fine when I remove theat particular line. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @maman Ok. Looks like you have problems with a database, because of a schema update takes a lot of time. In the same time, you have a few persistens.